# I'm using a TV as a monitor. Why are my resolution choices so limited when the TV supports more?

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, hdmi, tv

I am trying to use [this](http://tv.jvc.com/product.jsp?pathId=138&modelId=MODL029140) tv as a monitor.  As you can see, this tv supports 1920x1080 full HD.  However, when I plug it into my Windows computer (which can easily support this, it supports it on other monitors), I only get the following resolution choices:

[image: jvc tv resolutions on my pc]

Why is there no 1920x1080 option, like there is on my monitors at work?  How can I get full resolution working on this TV?  I have the TV set to "native", with other options being "full" and "natural", but that didn't change anything on the PC side.  I also have my TV set to "PC" mode.

Comment: How are you connecting the computer to the tv?  HDMI, DisplayPort, VGA, Component?

Comment: I connect via the HDMI port